# desktop wallpaper changer

Tags: settings, appearance

After updating to ubuntu 13-10 on both my Dell inspiron desktop as well as samsung netbook,the desktop wallpaper changer /appearance settings vanished from my ubuntus.Was the support removed.Although wallpapers can be changed by opening an image the appearence settings vanished.When i put 13.04 on my desktop again,it reappeared !
Whats wrong with my operations?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the following two packages, `gnome-control-center-signon` and `gnome-control-center-unity`. You can install them both by running the following command in a terminal

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center-signon gnome-control-center-unity
```

If they are already installed on your system, you can try to reinstall them by

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-control-center-signon gnome-control-center-unity
```